# Limit on GROUP BY in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to have a query that group my tracks for created date(month) and then it limit every group for max 10 results.

I'm trying to do in this way:

```
SELECT  "tracks".* 
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by tracks.votes_count DESC) AS r,
      t.*
      from tracks t
      where 1=1 ) x
where x.r <= 10
```

But it give me error on the from clause:

> ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "tracks"

Where I'm doing wrong ? How should be the correct query ?

Comment: SELECT x.* in main query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x` alias is exposed. So you need  change `tracks` alias to `x`.

```
SELECT  x.* 
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by tracks.votes_count DESC) AS r,
    t.*
    from tracks t
    where 1=1 ) x
where x.r <= 10
```

Comment: nice it's work...just a thing: how I can group by date(month) ?

Comment: @Riccardo As you said `group by date(month)` :)

Comment: yeah but how it know that should use the field created_at ?

Comment: @Riccardo I'm not sure I understand you correctly. You need to use full expression in `group by`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply:

```
SELECT *
FROM tracks
ORDER BY votes_count DESC NULLS LAST
LIMIT 10;
```